# install a CRAN package that imports a CRAN package that imports a Bioconductor package

Tags: r, bioconductor, software-installation

I have a CRAN package say `myPack`, that imports two CRAN packages, say `cranA` and `cranB`. These two packages import Bioconductor packages, say `biocA` and `biocB`. When I try installation of my package with `install.packages("myPack")` this ends up with error. I have to install `biocA` and `biocB` that are imported from both `cranA` and `cranB` in order to successfully install "myPack".

Does anyone have any idea how to do in order to successfully install `myPack` without having to install beforehand `biocA` and `biocB` from Bioconductor?

P.S. I have seen answers if you add `biocViews` to the `DESCRIPTION` file of `myPack`, but I think this is not sufficient for successful installation with `install.packages()`. The installation is successful if in addition you set the repositories with `setRepositories()` and you choose "CRAN" and "BioC software" and then you use `install.packages()` where the package inside `install.packages()` contains  `biocViews` to the `DESCRIPTION` file. So it seems that `biocViews` to the `DESCRIPTION` file does not automatically connect to Bioconductor repository.

Comment: I suggest you post this over at [support.bioconductor.org](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Comment: From my experience there is no good solutions. Many packages I use offer step-to-step guidance about installing CRAN and bioconductor packages separately in a certain order.